# Explain why this binary tree traversal algorithm has O(NlogN) time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity

I'm going through the Cracking the Coding Interview book right now and I'm doing a binary tree exercise. There is a snippet of code that is according to the book `O(NlogN)`, however, I don't understand why that is. I can understand if the algorithm was `O(N)`, but I don't know where the `logN` is coming from in their analysis.

```
int getHeight(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return -1; // Base case
    return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return true; // Base case

    int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(heightDiff) > 1) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        // Recurse
        return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we encounter an unbalanced node, we get an early return of false so this is the optimal case. The "worst case" for this algorithm to handle is a completely balanced tree, since we get no early returns of false. For the sake of this example, let's use a perfect binary tree with n nodes.

The first call would trigger getHeight() on each node so ~n nodes are visited. Total work for root level is O(n).

The next two calls (root.left.isBalanced() and root.right.isBalanced()) would trigger getHeight() on subsequent nodes but each one only calls it on ~1/2 n nodes. Total work for 1 height is also O(n).

The next 4 calls would call getHeight on n/4 nodes each. So total work for 2 height is also O(n).

If you see the pattern, the total work for each level of the tree is O(n), so total work for all levels is O(n) * levels in a perfect tree, which comes out to O(nlogn).

Answer (score 4):

The getHeight definitely has a linear complexity. It just visits every element in the subtree, so it is `O(k)` where `k` is the number of nodes in the subtree.

Now regarding the  isBalanced. First it computes the height (that is linear as we have seen earlier). But then if we are not so lucky we have to compute the isBalanced 2 more times: for the left and for the right subtrees. In the worst case we will be performing the linear computation for log N times.

You may study the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) that describes more generic cases.

In this particular case the parameters for the theorem are: `a = b = 2` and there is constant overhead on dividing the problem into subproblems.

Comment: For a tree with `n` nodes, O(length of subtree) is O(n), correct?

Comment: Not exactly. This is just the length of the subproblem which is smaller than n. But the fact is that you divide a larger problem into 2 different subproblems that are half of the size. At the end of the day n = 1/2n + 1/2n = 1/4n + 1/4n + 1/4n + 1/4n = ...

Comment: The `getHeight` takes `O(n)` time. We have no doubt about that. Now the `isBalanced` function divides the tree into two parts each time it's being called.

Comment: @0x499602D2 What is "length" of a subtree?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Then your first comment is a tautology and doesn't help in analyzing the OPs algorithm.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Umm...I was asking a question.

Comment: As for the "length of subtree" I agree that it was a bad statement. I should say the size of a subtree. I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ok, you were clarifying the first sentence of the answer here. I missed that part.

Comment: You should specify what the worst case is. That was the confusing part for me. I thought the worst case was an unbalanced tree on the last level, but it's actually a completely balanced tree.

Answer (score 3):

The worst case complexity of this algorithm happens in the case of balanced binary search tree since otherwise we return early. Consider the following balanced binary search tree 
[image: BST]
`isBalanced` function goes through all the nodes once(including the null children of leaf nodes). For each of these nodes it calls `getHeight` to calculate the height of the left and right child. So `getHeight` requires work proportional to size of subtree rooted on that node.
For null children of leaves (there are `16` such nodes) it requires constant amount of work. For the leaf nodes `(1, 3, 5, 7...)` we need double the work but our node is reduced by half (i.e. we have `8` nodes). One level above we need four times the work but our node is halved again.
In general if we have `N` nodes thus total amount of work is roughly

```
N + N/2*2 + N/4*4 + ... + N/N * 1
```

Every term of the sum is equal to `N`. How many terms are there? That's just the height of tree i.e. `lg(N)` since we reduce `N` by `2` until it reaches `1`. So total complexity is `O(N*lg(N))`

Comment: So the O(logN) is because we require up to O(logN) recursive calls since we may have to recurse up to the depths of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

In formal definition, if we suppose the complexity of `getHeight` is `G(n)`, and `T(n)` is the complexity of `isBalance` function, we will have `G(n) = G(n1) + G(n2) + 1` and `T(n) = T(n1) + T(n2) + G(n) + 1` such that `n1` is the size of left subtree and `n2` is the size of right subtree, and `n1 + n2 = n - 1`.

Try to expand `G(n) = (G(n11) + G(n12) + 1) + (G(n21)+G(n22) + 1) + 1`, such that `n11 + n12 + n21 + n22 = n1 - 1 + n2 - 1 = n - 3`. Hence, `G(n) = G(n11) + G(n12) + G(n21) + G(n22) + 3`. Using induction we can found that `G(n) = Theta(n)`. Therefore we have `T(n) = T(n1) + T(n2) + \Theta(n) + 1`.

Now, if the height of subtrees difference is greater than 1, the algorithm will return false and be terminated, the worst case is `|log(n2) - log(n1)| <= 1` (`log(n{i})` is the height of the subtree `i`). Hence, by powering `2`, we have `n2/n1 <= 2`. It means, `n1` and `n2` are a constant factor of `n` as we had `n1 + n2 = n -1`. Now, from [Akra-Bazzi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), by `p = 1` (approximately), and `g(n) = n` (as it is `\Theta(n)`), the complextiy of `T(n)` in the worst case is `n*(1 + integral(x/x^2, 1, n)) = n*(1 + integral(1/x, 1, n) = n * (1 + log(n))`. Therefore, `T(n) = O(n log(n))`.