# Why is the time complexity of this function to check the balance of a Binary Tree O(n log n)?

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-tree, big-o, logarithm

**Prompt from Cracking the Coding Interview by Gayle Laakmann McDowell:**

*Implement a function to check if a binary tree is balanced.
For this problem, a balanced tree is defined such that the heights
of the two subtrees of any node do not differ by more than one.*

(Example implementation below.)

**Question:** Can you help me understand why the author states that `isBalanced` has a
time complexity of `O(n log n)`? I get it to some degree and can memorize this just fine, but I can't conceptualize why this is the case like I can for other time complexities like `O(n^2)`.

```java
int getHeight(TreeNode root) {
  if (root == null) { return -1; }
  return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
  if (root == null) { return true; }

  int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
  if (Maths.abs(heightDiff) > 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
  }
}

// isBalanced([some node]) --> true/false
```

How do I visualize why `isBalanced` is considered `O(n log n)`?

Comment: The recurrence relation is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)` which is case 2 of the [master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/) so O(n log n).

Comment: Your `getHeight` function does not seems to store the calculated height anywhere. If you have to redo the whole operation each time for each node, I doubt the complexity will be `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O of finding out if a binary tree is balanced (From CTCI Book)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235257/big-o-of-finding-out-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced-from-ctci-book)

Comment: I think you can find answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193816/explain-why-this-binary-tree-traversal-algorithm-has-onlogn-time-complexity/56193945#56193945

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have BST

```
      4        // No of nodes 1
    /    \
   2      6    // No of nodes 2
 /  \    /  \
1    3  5    7 // No of nodes 4
```

Your function `isBalanced` is going through all nodes including the ones with no children and call `getHeight` to calculate the height of left and right child.

The recursive relation of the function would be

[image: isBalanced Recursive Relation]

which is derived from Master Theorem

[image: Master Theorem]

`a` = number of sub-problems in recursion

`n/b` = size of each sub-problem

`f(n)` = cost of work that has to be done outside the recursive calls

`a` is `2` because we have to visit both children nodes of each parent

`b` is `2` because if you notice the number of nodes reduce by half each time you go a level above (from bottom).

`f(n)` is `n` because we have to call `getHeight()` on each node

Which satisfies the second case of Master Theorem that is

[image: second case of Master Theorem]

Putting the values to prove `f(n) = O(n^logb(a))`

[image: Putting the values]

Thus we get the time complexity of `O(n log n)`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. His question was why is the time complexity O(n log n) instead of O(n^2) like he expected.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Is this acceptable? Thanks for pointing out my mistake.